# What is the density of $(W, Z)$ where $W = \frac{X}{X+Y}$ and $ Z = \frac{Y}{X+Y}$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

I have tried to use the method involving the Jacobian matrix but I am struggling to find the inverse of the function $f(x,y) = (\frac{x}{x+y}, \frac{y}{x+y})$.

We have that $X,Y \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inverse of $f$, for the two components of the result are related by $W+Z=1$. $f(1,2)=f(2,4)$, for example. It suffices to find the density of one of the two coordinates (e.g. by finding the density of $(X/(X+Y),Y)$) and then complementing to find the density of the other.

If $(W,Y)=(X/(X+Y),Y)$ then $YW/(1-W)=X$, i.e. $(X,Y)=(YW/(1-W),Y)$.

Comment: what do you mean by complementing?

Comment: @math111 To take the complement of $x$ means doing $1-x$.

Comment: How do we get the joint distribution of $(W,Z)$ from this? or is this linked to the complementing idea?

Comment: I am happy with obtaining the density of $W$ and $Z$ but how do we get the joint density?

Comment: How do you get the distribution of $W$ from $(W,Y)$

Comment: @math111 I just added the inverse map of $(X/(X+Y),Y)$ to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I am happy with getting the joint dist of (W,Y) but how would we marginalise to get the dist of W? It seems integrating over y won’t work as W has y dependence’s.

Comment: @math111 That is another question, please.